# Is there a better of way of "suggesting" to indicate a positive action?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-requests, objects

I have a sentence using *suggest*:

> Adults with a wide range of work experience can suggest young people the most effective strategies to look for a job.

The absence of "to" in the words "suggest young people" seems wrong.  But including "to," ,as in "can suggest to young people" doesn't sound right either. *Suggest to* in that usage could mean that the young people have that thought occur to them spontaneously: "It suggested to the young people that..."

Here, I want to say that adults are actually making a suggestion. What can I replace *suggest* or *suggest to* with, in order to make it clear that the adults are making a suggestion?

Comment: There are two possibilities: You can keep *experience* in the singular and change *various* to *a range of*; or you can use *various* with the plural *experiences*. You also need to insert *to*, as you suggest.. I should also change *strategies to look for a job* to *strategies for finding a job*. But that's a matter of style rather than grammar.

Comment: What @RonaldSole said, and you could consider "share with" as an alternative to "suggest to" and maybe shorten the last phrase to "the most effective job-hunting strategies."

Comment: 'Adults with various work experience can make suggestions to young people about the most effective strategies for job-seeking.' // 'Can suggest young people strategies' is ungrammatical; the non-volitional-agent usage of 'suggest' (eg 'their behaviour suggests that they're from a different group of meerkats') is admittedly vaguely possible here, but an unlikely reading.

Comment: Change "suggest" to "advise".  (It really should be "suggest to" in your above example anyway.  There is nothing in "suggest to" that implies a "spontaneous" thought.)

Comment: Most properly:  *Adults with various work experiences (or "varied work experience") can **advise** young people **on (or of)** the most effective strategies for job-seeking.*

Answer (score 1):

This phrasing offers an alternative to the use of "suggest":

> With their wide range of work experience, adults are ***in a good position to offer*** advice to young people about effective job-hunting strategies.

If you use the phrase ***in a position to***, here you convey the idea that it would be a good idea for adults to make use of their experience and offer to help young people.  The word ***good*** expresses your opinion a little more strongly, and the word ***offer*** further highlights that there is a choice here for adults to make.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage! We're looking for long answers that provide some [explanation and context](//english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). Please explain why your answer is right, ideally with [citations](//english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). Answers that don't include explanations may be [removed](//english.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: Rereading the original question, I think now that I misunderstood what she was trying to say.  I think she is looking for something like this: "With their wide range of work experience, adults are in a good position to offer advice to young people about effective job-hunting strategies."

Answer (score 0):

A word that fits your sentence grammatically and semantically is ***teach***:

> Adults … can ***teach*** young people the most effective strategies
>   to look for a job.

Unfortunately, *teach* is a stronger word than *suggest*. 
A person can *suggest* something just by mentioning it;
to *teach* usually entails explaining and/or demonstrating.